# strcmp with conditional statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, printf, conditional-statements, strcmp

Assuming buf will be either WIN LOSE or DRAW, (I have tested this to be the case), some of the if statements are not running at all. Only the first statement where buf is equal to WIN, the switch inside of the if statement will be reached. For the other two cases, where buf equals LOSE, or DRAW, the program does not enter the if statements, nor run the switch cases, and a segmentation fault happens. I can't seem to find the error. I am not good at comparing strings in C, if someone could please correct my mistake that would be great. Thank you.

**A chunk of code from the program**

```
const char* opp[1];
        printf("passed declarer comp\n");
        if(strcmp(buf, "WIN")==0) {
                printf("Entered win statement\n");
                switch(choice) {
                        case 1: opp[0]="Rock"; break;
                        case 2: opp[0]="Paper"; break;
                        case 3: opp[0]="Scissors"; break;
                }
        }

        if(strcmp(buf, "LOSE")==0) {
                printf("Entered lose statement\n");
                switch(choice) {
                        case 1: opp[0]="Scissors"; break;
                        case 2: opp[0]="Rock"; break;
                        case 3: opp[0]="Paper"; break;
                }
        }

        if(strcmp(buf, "DRAW")==0) {
                printf("Entered draw statement\n");
                opp[0] = playerChose[0];
        }

        printf("passed logic\n");
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        printf("%s\n",opp[0]);
        printf("The other player chose %s, you %s\n", opp[0], buf);
```

Comment: I guess you need to show [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First of all why using array of 1 pointer, just use the pointer . Basically they will do same task .

Comment: Use `else-if` to improve performance. And add some error handling, what if the strings are not what you expect?

Comment: I had to add a lot of code around this to make it work but cannot replicate the problem you report. Make it a [mcve].

Comment: Your debugger will gladly tell you _where_ exactly the segfault happens.

Comment: I don't see anything really wrong in your code, the problem must be elsewhere in some code you didn't show. Are you sure the content of `playerChose[0]` is correct?

Comment: _" (I have tested this to be the case)"_ : how did you test this ?

Comment: "Assuming buf will be either WIN LOSE or DRAW"` is wrong.   `printf("passed declarer comp\n");` --> `printf("passed declarer comp '%s' %d\n", buf, choice); opp[1] = "?";`